# Low and high impedance of low pass stepped impedance filter

Tags: rf, filter, transmission-line, microwave, microstrip

I'm designing a low pass chebyshev filter using stepped impedance.

I'm using the book 'Microstrip Filters for RF/Microwave Applications' as a reference.

I have difficulty understanding how low and high impedances are defined. The book uses \$Z_{0L} = 93\,\Omega\$ and \$Z_{0C} = 24\,\Omega\$. I could not find an explanation for these values, I searched several articles but all uses an impedance between 20 and 120 Ω but does not explain how to calculate.

How can I get to this definition?

Comment: If you're doing RF, "low" or "high" impedances are relative to 50\$\Omega\$.  If you're doing video, 75\$\Omega\$.  The "why" is partially traditional, and partially because that's what Just Works(TM).  If you're doing digital logic, then 120\$\Omega\$, for the same reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that book, but chances are that \$Z_0\$ is simply the impedance of that piece of microstrip; it's pretty standard to use \$Z_0\$ as the symbol for reference impedance.